# Meaning of android.content.UriMatcher

Tags: java, android, uri

What is Uri Matcher in `android.content.UriMatcher`

How to use it?
Can someone please explain meaning of following three line of code?

```
  uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
  uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cte", uriCode);
  uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cte/*", uriCode);
  int res = uriMatcher.match(uri);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

UriMatcher is a handy class when you are writing a ContentProvider or some other class that needs to respond to a number of different URIs. In your example, a user could query your provider with URIs such as:

```
myprovider://cte
```

or

```
myprovider://cte/somestring
```

When you construct a UriMatcher, you need to have separate codes for each URI (not just "uriCode" as in your example). I usually make my UriMatcher instance static, and add the URIs in a static constructor:

```
private static final int CTE_ALL = 1;
private static final int CTE_FIND = 2;
private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cte", CTE_ALL);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cte/*", CTE_FIND);
}
```

Then in your ContentProvider you would do something like this in your query method:

```
Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    int res = uriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (res) {
        case CTE_ALL:
            //TODO create a results Cursor with all the CTE results
            break;
        case CTE_FIND:
            //TODO create a results Cursor with the single CTE requested
            break;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: "I usually make my UriMatcher instance static" why?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch staitc block get called when class get laoded before any object creation. This  makes the uri matcher ready to work while loading class..

Answer (score 5):

I found the following videos to be useful:

[URI Basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9Lq_7VqpQo)

[URI Matcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTPYie9A7iI)

In essence, what you are trying to do is, have an ID or a number associated to different URIs. When you use addUri, a code/number/ID gets created against the URI. When you request a match(), the corresponding code is returned.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing I wanted to add that wasn't clear for me first time I used UriMatcher.

Is that if you want to parse an HTTP url then as an *AUTHORITY* parameter in the **addURI** you need to pass the target domain name. For example:

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("http://example.com/foo");
UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

// if not "example.com" below the match will always return -1 result
sURIMatcher.addURI("example.com", "/foo", 123);

int match = sURIMatcher.match(mUri);
```

[UriMatcher Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher) doesn't cover this case and it's not clear what's this authority parameter for.
Gosh if I knew that it would save me some time!